# Deleting columns at regular intervals

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file with about 25000 columns and 3,000 lines. Now starting with column 4, I want to delete columns 3-5 at the interval of 8th column till the end.

Example:

The input file

```
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10 c11 c12 c13 c14 c15 c16 c17 c18 c19 c20
d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7 d8 d9 d10 d11 d12 d13 d14 d15 d16 d17 d18 d19 d20
```

Now I want the output file

```
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c9 c10 c11 c12 c13 c17 c18 c19 c20
d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d9 d10 d11 d12 d13 d17 d18 d19 d20
```

I hope my question is not a confusing one. I know how to print at regular intervals but don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Sorry confused. Why is c15-c17 removed instead of c14-c16? Please elaborate your logic with respect to your output.

Comment: @jaypal: you are right. I apologize for the mistake. I have rectified it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way is probably something like:

```
awk '{
printf "%s %s %s", $1, $2, $3
for (i=4; i<=NF; i++)
    if ( ((i-3)%8) !~ /^[345]$/)
        printf " %s", $i
print ""
}' file
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c9 c10 c11 c12 c13 c17 c18 c19 c20
d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d9 d10 d11 d12 d13 d17 d18 d19 d20
```

It might need the math tweaked but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Clever, I gave up after few wasted attempts.